# Flutter: Tap delay with GestureDetector in a Tile of a GridView

Tags: gridview, dart, flutter, gesturedetector

Normally, the below behavior is quick in nature. However, inside a GridView (or any ScrollView I assume (tried ListView, too)) the performance seems to be very poor. When I tap on the screen the opacity of the Container increases, but after a delay. Any idea what I am missing?

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: MyWidget()
        )
      );
    }
}
class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  double opacity = 0.2;
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 3
        ),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                opacity = 0.2;                
              });
            },
            onTapDown: (details) {
              setState(() {
                opacity = 1.0;                
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red.withAlpha((255 * opacity).toInt())
            )
          );
        },
      );
    }
}
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
      return MyWidgetState();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Maybe `Listener` would be faster in your case

```dart
Listener(
  onPointerDown: (PointerDownEvent event) {
    setState(() {
      opacity = 1.0;
    });
  },
  onPointerUp: (PointerUpEvent event) {
    setState(() {
      opacity = 0.2;
    });
  },
  child: Container(
      color: Colors.red.withAlpha((255 * opacity).toInt())
  ),
)
```

Comment: Tried it out, works like a charm. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: You're welcome. If this is solution - would you mark answer? )))

Comment: Actually, I still had the GridView replaced with a column in my testing. So now I tried your approach and while it shortens the delay, the performance is still a little worse than using a column. Any idea why that is? Will mark your answer, though. It does increase performance.

Comment: Did you try `GridView.count` instead of `GridView.builder`? Does it change delay?

Comment: It doesn't change much. But what I am referring to is really a response to a ridiculously short tap. Scenario: When I'm tapping once as fast as I can and have the opacity increase on pointerDown and decrease on pointerUp, then I see no change. However, if I have the opacity change after the first tap and stay like that, I see the change, which means the taps are being recognized. Does this maybe mean that the tap is too short for the calculated opacity change to be visible at all?

Comment: If you check logs - you see that all taps work. But wen you tap really quick - `onPointerUp` returns opacity to previous level, so you can't catch moment of changing - it becomes so quick. `GestureDecector` works too, `Listener` just little quicker. I think that building of `Column` takes less time than `GridView.builder`

Comment: Right, I think a solution would be to let pointerUp always trigger an actual animation. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's amazing - works 10000000x times faster. I wonder why it works so much faster. On the other hand, it incepts scrolling event on the item as if it was tap as well...