# GestureDetector with HitTestBehavior.opaque not work properly to hide keyboard screen

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector, event-behaviour

I want to hide screen keyboard by onTap outside `TextField` or anywhere on screen.
Then i wrap my `Scaffold` with `GestureDetector` like below.
i already try both with `onTap` and `onTapDown`.

```
 GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
  onTapDown: (_) {
    printLog("hide keyboard ${_.localPosition}");
    FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
    },
  child: Scaffold()
```

Everything work fine on simple widget (small amount of widget ). But when i have much widget rendered, the function to hide keyboard only called sometimes. not every action ontap Happend on my screen.

eg in my scaffold body:

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 50,
    itemBuilder: ((context, index) => GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            printLog("tap on card");
          },
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 3),
            height: 60,
            color: Colors.blueGrey,
          ),)))
```

here the console log.
as we can see (line 4) , the `print('[Debug] hide keyboard Offset()')` do not called every `onTap()` happend on my screen.

```
I/flutter (15284): [Debug] hide keyboard Offset(281.5, 330.2)
(2)I/flutter (15284): [Debug] tap on card
I/flutter (15284): [Debug] hide keyboard Offset(253.5, 292.0)
(3)I/flutter (15284): [Debug] tap on card   => i tapped 3 times on my card 
I/flutter (15284): [Debug] tap on card   => until the 4th tap, keybord not hide
I/flutter (15284): [Debug] hide keyboard Offset(186.2, 279.3)
I/flutter (15284): [Debug] tap on card
```

but when i do `longpress` on my card, the function hide keyboard always will be called.
i assume there is a delay on `GestureDetector` while catching the onTap. so user need to tap longer than usual. But its not good thing, because i cant tell the user to press longer on screen everytime use the app.
.

.

> **what i want to achieve is, every clicking outside of my `Textfield`,  it should called hide keyboard function without delayed.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update the latest version

we can use a new property named `onTapOutside`. No need to wrap all widgets with `GestureDetector`

```
TextFormField(
  onTapOutside: (event) =>
      FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
  controller: _ctrl,
```

---

#### old answer

reff: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53063398/12838877

so i change the `GestureDetector` to `Listener` . it more faster.

documentation said:

> Rather than listening for raw pointer events, consider listening for
> higher-level gestures using GestureDetector.

and its works fine as expected now.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Listener(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onPointerDown: (_) {
        printLog("hide keyboard ${_.localPosition}");
        FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
      },
      child: Scaffold()
```